# Get Absolute Expiration event from ObjectCache

Tags: c#, caching, .net-4.8

I'm using an **ObjectCache** object as `MemoryCache.Default` (System.Runtime.Caching) and my policy contains AbsoluteExpiration.

*for example*:

```
ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default
cahce.Add(key, reading, new CacheItemPolicy { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(20)});
```

I would like to save the objects before it's being removed.

Is it possible to catch the event of expiration, before item removed from cache?

Comment: `new CacheItemPolicy { ... , RemovedCallback = ev => { //save ev.CacheItem }}` ? Though it happens after the item was removed, but is there any real difference for you and why?

Comment: There's also an `UpdateCallback` which is called before the item is removed

Comment: thanks, can you please give an example ?

Comment: @fatalica example of what exactly?

Comment: thanks @GuruStron, i was able to use callback as you described

Comment: @fatalica was glad to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add an Entry in MemoryCache with `Add` function, you can add `CacheItemPolicy`.

This class have this fields:

```
     private DateTimeOffset _absExpiry;
        private TimeSpan _sldExpiry;
        private Collection<ChangeMonitor> _changeMonitors;
        private CacheItemPriority _priority;
        private CacheEntryRemovedCallback _removedCallback;
        private CacheEntryUpdateCallback _updateCallback;
```

What you need is `_removedCallback`.

Source code: [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Caching/System/Caching/MemoryCache.cs,4ad4e64ee60474b6) and [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Caching/System/Caching/CacheItemPolicy.cs,4ad4e64ee60474b6).